# Get width in percentage from Resizable divs from jQuery UI on load and on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I got these two divs next to each other. Both of the divs can already be resized by using the jQuery UI.

On resizing the divs I grab the width make it into a percentage and output it to the corresponding inputs but something strange happens.

The HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="div1"> My Data1
     <input type="text" class="div1">
   </div> 
   <div id="div2"> My Data2
     <input type="text" class="div2">
   </div> 
</div>
```

The Javascript:

```
$("#div1").resizable();
$('#div1').resize(function(){
   $('#div2').width($("#parent").width()-$("#div1").width()); 
});
$(window).resize(function(){

   var div1width = $(".div1").width() / $('.div1').parent().width() * 100;
   // Paste percentage into the inputs
   $('.div1').val(div1width);

   var div2width = $(".div2").width() / $('.div2').parent().width() * 100;
   // Paste percentage into the inputs
   $('.div2').val(div2width);
});
```

The CSS:

```
#parent{
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
}
#div1{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
    background-color:#A2A;
}
#div2{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
    background-color:#BBB;
}
.ui-resizable-e {
    cursor: e-resize;
    width: 7px;
    right: -5px;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
}
```

The fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uvcxfmfy/1/

What happens is that when I make for instance div1 smaller the width percentage goes up even all the way over 800%. When I make it wider the width percentage stops at 20%. So something is wrong but I cant find it where.

## What I am trying to achieve.

On page load both divs should have 50% width. When I make div1 smaller it should go all the way to 0% when I make it bigger it should go to 100%.

This means that if div1 is set at 25% that div2 will have 75%
When div1 is set at 58% then div2 is 42%.

Thanks everyone for helping.

Comment: OK, again, as I noted on the previous iteration of this question, `$(".div1").width()` is getting you the width of the `<input>` element that has class "div1". The parent of that `<input>` is the `<div>` with id "div1". I'm not sure I understand the point of computing the ratio of the input element width to the div width.

Comment: Oh that is simple to explain. The end user sees in the backend of the application basically what we see in the fiddle without those inputs those will be hidden. The user then drag and drops the `columns (#div1 & 2)` until the user is satisfied. So lets say one is 25% the other 75%. These values are then also into the hidden inputs. On save of the application the inputs are stored. Then on the frontend those saved values are used to generate the column widths. Hopefully this clears it up. I don't think there is a point to have added all this in the initial question?

Comment: @Pointy The inputs have actually nothing to do with the question they just simply display the value. For the purpose of this question it could have been a console.log or alert aswell. I just want to make the divs resizable and return the width in percentage from 0 to 100.

Comment: well the inputs sure do have something to do with the way that fiddle works, because `$(".div1")` refers to the `<input>` element inside the div with id "div1".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you find it helpful.
You should use this math to get percent:

```
Math.round(( docWidth - elemWidth ) / docWidth * 100)
```

---

Im just order your code and change the calc line, look at this **example**:

```
$("#div1").resizable();

$('#div1').resize(function(){
   $('#div2').width($("#parent").width()-$("#div1").width()); 
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    elementResize()
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    elementResize()
});

function elementResize(){
   $('#div2').width($("#parent").width()-$("#div1").width()); 
   $('#div1').height($("#parent").height()); 

   var parentwidth = $("#parent").width(),
       div1width = $("#div1").width(),
       div2width = $("#div2").width(),
       div1percentage = Math.round((div1width / parentwidth) * 100),
       div2percentage = Math.round((div2width / parentwidth) * 100);

   $('.div1').val(div1percentage);
   $('.div2').val(div2percentage);
}
```

**[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5kqr9vdy/)**

Comment: Thanks @Zeev Katz and yes I find it helpful. I just checked the fiddle but don't really see the point ;-) When you resize it for a little bit just a pixel you can see what I mean. The input on the left should say something like `80%` and the one on the right should say something like `20%` but instead on the left it says `24.9%` and right `99.41%` so I think I messed something up in calculating the width.

Comment: Hey man thanks hadn't expected it anymore but really like it. Love the fact that you put it into a function instead like me copy/pasting it. Is there a specific reason you went for .floor() instead of .round()?

Comment: Sorry I just noticed that the values are the wrong way around. Ehm how to explain... When i make the width smaller the percentage goes up instead of down. So instead of saying 10% it says 90%.

In my own fiddle I redone the calculation entirely and it is working but like your way of the function better. Could you update this fiddle with the function please? https://jsfiddle.net/uvcxfmfy/11/

Comment: Can you edit your answer to reflect this latest fiddle and also change the fiddle link in your answer. I am removing my answer as this one is better. Is it possible to put a cap onto it. So it never goes beyond 100% or below 0%. When I move the first div all the way to the right the input says 101% which will break the purpose.

Comment: Accepted the answer and removed my own as this is the one I am going to use. Could you help with implementing this cap to it? If you want I would like to go to chat to explain it a bit better!

Comment: Thanks, Zeev. This worked out great for what I am working on. I made up a demo for the width in PX instead of %. https://jsfiddle.net/carrzkiss/p85f3mwu/11/